# Are there other sources of suggested sets?

Tags: dominion

I have all the Dominion sets and really prefer to play the suggested sets of kingdom cards that come with the rules.  I find that these sets often are thought out really well and have several interesting strategies to explore.  When using randomizers (apps or just drawing randomly) I find that the sets seldom offers that many interesting strategies.

So:
I wonder if anyone knows of good suggested sets of kingdom cards?  Have you played with combinations that provide several strategy types?  Is there a source of suggested sets anywhere?  Somewhere where people can vote on sets?

I am sorry if the question is a bit vauge, but all I really want is to find some suggestions for good sets, not just random sets.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that even the most "boring" looking set almost always has some fantastic, and fun, strategies to be discovered.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One great resource is [Dominion Deck Builder](http://www.dominiondeck.com/), a website that allows users to design and save kingdoms. They can be voted on, discussed, etc. *Edit* This website is no longer available.

This is also a frequently-discussed topic at the Dominion Strategy Forum. Here are a few threads that each list several Kingdom setups that people have suggested, and in the latter 2 threads, voted on:

http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=11251.0

http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=6785.0 (Older, so does not contain Dark Ages or Guilds)

http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=11100